# Classification of coherent sheaves on $\Bbb P^1$ with a doubled point (nonseparated)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be the scheme obtained by gluing two copies of $\Bbb P^1_k$ along $D(x)$ (basically the projective version of the line with two origins). Is there a good classification of coherent sheaves on $X$? By analogy with the case of $\Bbb P^1$ it seems clear that a coherent sheaf splits as a direct sum of a locally free part and a torsion part, but I'm worried that the extremely convenient property that a locally free sheaf on $\Bbb P^1$ is a direct sum of $\mathcal{O}(d_i)$ for various $d_i$ won't hold (the proof I know is linear algebra on the transition matrix, which I can't figure out how to adapt to this case).

Has this been written down somewhere before, or can anyone help me get to the right answer?

Comment: Not sure, but if $i_1,i_2$ are the two inclusions $P=\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow X$ and $U =P \backslash \{0\} \cong \mathbb{A}^1$ then the category of modules on $X$ should be equivalent to the category of the $(L,M,i)$ where $L,M$ are modules on $P$ and $i: L_{|U} \cong M_{|U}$. 

A locally free module on $U$ is free and is determined up to isomorphism by its rank. It also has *many* automorphisms, which usually do not extend to $P$. But automorphisms of locally free modules on $\mathbb{P}^1$ (as sums of $O(d)$) are scalar matrices. That’s why I think it’s much messier than $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Do you know the classification of coherent sheaves on $ \mathbb{P}^1 $? Every such sheaf (more generally, on any nonsingular curve) splits as a vector bundle + torsion sheaf. We know the v.b's and the indecomposable torsion sheaves are supported at points, so there are lots of ways to glue these on $ X $.  So I too, think the answer for $ X $ is going to be messy.

Comment: @CraniumClamp yes, I mentioned this proof and a couple of it's details in the post. It's reassuring to hear from others that the problem I was stuck on is probably complicated, I guess.